# fortran Int64 Integer too big

Tags: int, fortran

I am trying to set an integer using `Integer(int64)` and having a problem setting to. When I call `huge`, I get `9223372036854775807`. But when I try to set `4807526976` which should be within range I do get a compile error.

```
 Integer (Int64) :: i

  Write (*,*) huge (i)
 i = 4807526976
 Write (*,*) "i: ", i
```

Compiler is giving me

```
Error: Integer too big for its kind at (1).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int64` is not the the default kind for integers. When evaluating the RHS of the assignment, the compiler tries to use the default integer kind for `4807526976` end (consequently) issues the warning.

Specifying the kind manually

```
i = 4807526976_int64
```

works like a charm. BTW: `ifort` seems to be intelligent enough to correctly chose the kind on its own ;-)